# Generalized Terms for Categorizing an Occupation Label

Tags: synonyms, context

This feels like a longshot, so pardon me if it’s an ill-formed question for this forum…

I’m trying to define a two-phrase structure that describes any person’s role or occupation.  Here are several examples to demonstrate the scope of its use:

- Commanding Officer, USS Nimitz
- CEO, Cool Stuff Inc
- Waitress, Joe’s Bar
- Student, Pinewood University

Each role label has two parts: The first I could probably call the “title” for the role.  However, the second part covers a wide variety of contexts (a business, an institution or organization, a military post or ship, etc.).  I’d like to find a general term for the second portion of the label that applies to any of those situations so that all roles can be defined by a Title and a [Something].  The [Something] would provide the context for the title, but the term "context" seems too general to clearly convey the type of information I want the term to portray.

I would appreciate any suggestions for a general term I could use to describe the second, “context” phrase within such an occupation label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about: *role, **affiliation***?

> **affiliation** *noun*
> **:** the state or relation of being closely associated or affiliated with a particular person, group, party, company, etc.
>  <sub>Source:
> [Merriam-Webster —
> *affiliation*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affiliation)</sub>

Comment: I like that, so I gave it a +1. I was thinking of 'workplace' or 'organisation' but realised that 'workplace' isn't really right for the corporation or the university and that 'organisation' isn't really right for the ship. Affiliation is much better.

Comment: That's not bad.  I'll mull it over a little more, but I like it.

Comment: Decided to go with this answer as it seems to fit the bill.  Thanks again!